# pandas shifting delta between rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like:

```
Area    Sector  Date          Amt
FICC    GOV     31/01/2019    100
EQ      CORP    31/01/2019     50
FICC    GOV     31/03/2019    200
EQ      CORP    31/03/2019    100
FICC    GOV     31/12/2018     50
EQ      CORP    31/12/2018     25
```

I want to get the delta based on dates. So the output that I am expecting is

```
Area    Sector  Date          Amt  Delta
FICC    GOV     31/12/2018     50
EQ      CORP    31/12/2018     25
FICC    GOV     31/01/2019    100     50
EQ      CORP    31/01/2019     50     25
FICC    GOV     31/03/2019    200    100
EQ      CORP    31/03/2019    100     50
```

Is there an efficient way in pandas to achieve the above ?

Comment: apologies. thanks for pointing it out. I corrected the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` the date, then `groupby` + `diff`

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.sort_values('Date')
df['Delta'] = df.groupby(['Area', 'Sector']).Amt.diff()

   Area Sector       Date  Amt  Delta
4  FICC    GOV 2018-12-31   50    NaN
5    EQ   CORP 2018-12-31   25    NaN
0  FICC    GOV 2019-01-31  100   50.0
1    EQ   CORP 2019-01-31   50   25.0
2  FICC    GOV 2019-03-31  200  100.0
3    EQ   CORP 2019-03-31  100   50.0
```